# Create procedure in mysql to create each select query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    a.CREATED, 
    a.FIRST_REVISION, 
    a.SECOND_REVISION , 
    a.THIRD_REVISION , 
    a.FOURTH_REVISION, 
    a.FIFTH_REVISION
FROM tb_master_repair_estimate a
WHERE a.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = 91
```

I got result like this :

```
+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| CREATED             | FIRST_REVISION | SECOND_REVISION | THIRD_REVISION | FOURTH_REVISION | FIFTH_REVISION |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2016-09-26 04:32:22 | 2016-09-25     | 2016-09-25      | 2016-09-25     | NULL            | NULL           |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can I create procedure with logic like this ?

```
I will check in field FIRST_REVISION,
   if null, I used data CREATED to another query
   break;
I will check IN field SECOND_REVISION
   if null, I use data FIRST_REVISION to another query
   break
I will check IN field THIRD_REVISION
   if null, I use data SECOND_REVISION to another query
   break
```

I was wondering, it is possible something like procedure to manage it?

Please, give an example, I am newbie to create a function or procedure in mysql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_CHECK_LAST_REVISED
     RETURNS DATE

BEGIN
    /*  LIKE THIS ONE */

END;
```

I create a procedure like this :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P_CHECK_LAST_REVISED; 

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE P_CHECK_LAST_REVISED(id_cari int(10))

BEGIN

DECLARE pre varchar(50);
DECLARE one varchar(50);
DECLARE two varchar(50);
DECLARE three varchar(50);
DECLARE four varchar(50);
DECLARE five varchar(50);
DECLARE last_revision varchar(50);

SELECT CREATED, FIRST_REVISION, SECOND_REVISION, THIRD_REVISION, FOURTH_REVISION, FIFTH_REVISION        
    INTO one, two,three, four, five
    FROM tb_master_repair_estimate a
WHERE a.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;

IF one IS NULL THEN
    SELECT b.* FROM tb_repair_detail b
    WHERE b.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;

ELSEIF two IS NULL THEN
    SELECT c.* FROM tb_repair_detail_first_revision c
    WHERE c.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;

ELSEIF three IS NULL THEN
    SELECT d.* FROM tb_repair_detail_second_revision d
    WHERE d.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;   

ELSEIF four IS NULL THEN
    SELECT e.* FROM tb_repair_detail_third_revision e
    WHERE e.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;   

ELSEIF five IS NULL THEN
    SELECT f.* FROM tb_repair_detail_fourth_revision f
    WHERE f.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;   

ELSE
    SELECT g.* FROM tb_repair_detail_fifth_revision g
    WHERE gx.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = id_cari;  

END IF;

END;
//
```

So, `call P_CHECK_LAST_REVISED(92)`, I GOT ERROR LIKE THIS :

```
The used select statment hav a different number columns
```

Comment: yes very easily with `IF` blocks and select into vars. You would decide what params you want to pass into the proc such as estimate id etc.

Comment: Please give me an example

Comment: I would but here is the thing. You have 180 questions and 5 accepted answers. idk.

Comment: Okey, i am not intent on that, sorry.

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: cut and paste the exact error

Comment: You are selecting 6 columns into 5 variables.

Answer (score -1):

hi may be you can try this

> `DELIMITER //
>
> Create procedure test(p_REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID int)
>
> Begin
>
> SELECT
>
> a.CREATED,
>
> a.FIRST_REVISION,
>
> a.SECOND_REVISION ,
>
> a.THIRD_REVISION ,
>
> a.FOURTH_REVISION,
>
> a.FIFTH_REVISION
>   FROM tb_master_repair_estimate a
>
> WHERE a.REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID = p_REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID
>
> End;`

Comment: Can you add the code to follow the logic requested by the OP?